# How do I edit a plugin's core properly?

Tags: plugins

I'm a WP beginner.

So I'm using a plugin called breadcrumb-trail. I'm about to upgrade it, but I noticed that I had tweaked `/breadcrumb-trail/breadcrumb-trail.php` a little bit in the past. How would I extract these changes to another file so that they won't be deleted when I upgrade breadcrumb-trail?

here's an example of one of my changes (I commented out the 2nd line of the array):
before:

```
    $defaults = array(
        'separator' => '&raquo;',
        /*'before' => '<span class="breadcrumb-title">' . __( 'Browse:', $textdomain ) . '</span>',*/
        'after' => false,
        'front_page' => true,
        'show_home' => __( 'Home', $textdomain ),
        'echo' => true
    );
```

after:

```
    $defaults = array(
        'separator' => '/',
        'before' => '<span class="breadcrumb-title">' . __( 'Browse:', $textdomain ) . '</span>',
        'after' => false,
        'front_page' => true,
        'show_home' => __( 'Home', $textdomain ),
        'echo' => true
    );
```

I'm asking more for general practices when editing a plugin's core. I have other plugins that I have modified.

Answer (score 4):

If you look a little further down in the source of [Breadcrumb Trail](http://wordpress.org/plugins/breadcrumb-trail/), you'll notice this line:

```
/* Apply filters to the arguments. */
$args = apply_filters( 'breadcrumb_trail_args', $args );
```

The author has made it possible for you to do exactly what you need, **without editing the core file!** Simply hook into the `breadcrumb_trail_args` filter in your `functions.php`:

```
function wpse_104094_breadcrumb_trail_args( $args ) {
    $args['before'] = '';
    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'breadcrumb_trail_args', 'wpse_104094_breadcrumb_trail_args' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless it is a plugin you've created or maintain you *don't* edit it or you end up with these issues, though if you were to track your changes with a version control system like [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) it is easier to manage but still high maintenance and ill advised.

Best case for what you are doing would be to [create and then apply a patch](http://ariejan.net/2009/10/26/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-git/). I still don't recommend hacking someone else's plugin though. It is going to be a recurring headache.